# Open file highlight color changes in Vim when used on a remote server on macOS Big Sur (11.1)

Tags: terminal, vim, macos-bigsur

I use the terminal and it has set to ‘Pro’ scheme which has a dark background. When I SSH to a Linux server (CentOS 8.3.2011) and use VIM open a file, the color of the keywords in the file changes after a few seconds (I have set ‘syntax on’ of Vim). I have try other scheme of terminal, that not happens.

I also tried iTerm2 with default scheme, also works well.

Is this a bug or setting error?

Initially looks like this:

[image: Initially looks like this.]

Then after a few seconds it looks like this:

[image: Then after a few seconds it looks like this.]

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to recreate this issue using macOS Big Sur (11.1) using CentOS 8 (8.3.2011) via a VirtualBox VM. I created a new window in Terminal (macOS) and used the “Pro” theme and the screen consistently looks like the second screenshot in your question. I never see colors that look like your first screenshot.

Here is a screenshot of being logged into CentOS 8 via SSH and opening the main Apache config file with Vim.

[image: Screenshot of being logged into CentOS 8 via SSH and opening the main Apache config file with Vim]

Comment: Do you use the terminal(set to PRO scheme or basic scheme with the system dark mode)  ssh to the centos8 run in Virutualbox? I have tried other ssh client, all works well, the screen consistently looks like the second screenshot of my post.

Comment: @JianxinYu Yes. Updated my answer.  I created a new window in Terminal (macOS) and used the “Pro” theme and the screen consistently looks like the second screenshot in your question.